# center image horizontally inside overflow:hidden div

Tags: css

I have a parent div with `width:100%` and `overflow:hidden`
I need to place an image of `2500-3000px` inside it, but have the image horizontally centered (cropped left and right) so the main center section of the image shows on smaller screens, but without horizontal scrollbar.
I can't use `background-image` since the image is dynamically added via php.
Please help.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you know the width and height of the image beforehand (i.e. they're all the same) then you can use the old `margin`/`position` trick:

```css
#myImage {
    height: the image's height;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -half the image's width;
    margin-top: -half the image's height;
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
    width: the image's width;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

CSS:

```
 div {background:salmon; width:100%; height:200px; overflow:hidden;}
 img {left: 50%; margin-left:-1500px; position:relative;}
```

HTML:

```
 <div><img src="" /></div>
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/SV69s/)

Answer (score 0):

Say myImg.jpg is 100x100px:

```
<div style="overflow:hidden; width:100%;">
    <img src="myImg.jpg" style="left: 50%; top:50%; position:relative; margin:-50px 0 0 -50px; width:100px; height:100px;" />
</div>
```